# How to Install the `thinkdsp` Package for Python

Tags: python, signal-processing

Below is a table summarizing the steps I have successfully completed so far:

|  | Description | Windows 10 powershell command |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (1) | run powershell | `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION>` |
| (2) | create new project folder | `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION>`**`mkdir myDSP`** |
| (3) | check installed Python versions | `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION>`**`py -0`** |
|  |  | `-V:3.10 Python 3.10 (64-bit)` |
|  |  | `-V:3.8 Python 3.8 (64-bit)` |
|  |  | `-V:3.7 Python 3.7 (64-bit)` |
| (4) | change to the project | `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION>`**`cd myDSP`** |
| (5) | create virtual environment | `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION>`**`py -3.8-64 -m venv myenv`** |
| (6) | activate virtual environment | `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION>`**`.\myenv\Scripts\activate`** |
| (7) | install dsp package | `(myenv)` `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION\myDSP>`**`pip install thinkx`** |
| (8) | create new python file | `(myenv)` `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION\myDSP>`**`New-Item script.py`** |

In my `script.py`, I've included two import statements to make use of the `SinSignal` and `decorate` methods:

```
from thinkdsp import SinSignal
from thinkdsp import decorate
```

Upon running the `script.py` with the command: `(myenv)` `PS C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION\myDSP>`**`python .\script.py`**|, the following error is encountered in the terminal:

```
C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION\myDSP\myenv\lib\site-packages\thinkdsp.py:32: UserWarning: Can't import Audio from IPython.display; Wave.make_audio() 
will not work.
  warnings.warn("Can't import Audio from IPython.display; "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from thinkdsp import decorate
ImportError: cannot import name 'decorate' from 'thinkdsp' (C:\Users\WORKINGSTATION\myDSP\myenv\lib\site-packages\thinkdsp.py)
```

**Question:** Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

**Further Investigation:**
I compared the `thinkdsp.py` file (downloaded via python pip installer) with the `thinkdsp.py` file (downloaded on git here https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP/blob/master/code/thinkdsp.py). I indeed see alot differences. Also that the  method `decorate` is missing in the `thinkdsp.py` file which I downloaded via python pip installer. see the the picture below for the comarion of both files (left: `thinkdsp.py` file downloaded via python pip installer, right: with `thinkdsp.py` downloaded on git here https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP/blob/master/code/thinkdsp.py).

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the `from thinkdsp import decorate` and use `thinkdsp.decorate` instead?

Comment: @AndrejKesely: thanks for reply. Do you mean writing `from thinkdsp import thinkdsp.decorate` instead of `from thinkdsp import decorate`? Best regards

Comment: Yes, you can try that or just use `import thinkdsp` and use `thinkdsp.decorate` in the code.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: it does not works. But I could figuring out that the method `decorate` is missing inside the `thinkdsp.py` file which I downloaded using `pip install thinkx`

Answer (score 2):

If using a jupyter notebook simply run this cell:

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('thinkdsp.py'):
    !wget https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP/raw/master/code/thinkdsp.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is still relevant (and if this is the same package), but according to thinkdsp author:

> A key thing to understand is that thinkdsp.py is not a package you have to install; it is just a module -- that is, a file that contain Python code.

[source of the quote](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP/issues/90#issuecomment-1348888752)

So, someone made a pip-installable package out of it (thinkx), but on github I can see it was updated 7 years ago. While original thinkdsp repo was updated recently (and I guess was updated many times all those years).

Comment: thanks for the hint. I edited my question. since I could do further investigation. I could figuring out that the method `decorate` is missing inside the `thinkdsp.py` file which I downloaded using `pip install thinkx`

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer I suggest downloading original version and either copy/paste all files need to your project (note the license) or make repository yourself. I can see `requirements.txt` file is there, so you need just to, make some sane folder structure, add some `__init__.py` files inside all folders and basic `setup.py` file